# Finding depth of specified element in an array of arrays (or list of lists etc.)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, pseudocode

I've to create a function (using pseudocode) which returns depth of specified element in an array (with optional arrays inside), e.g.:

```
def array[] = {"a", {"b", {"c"}, "d"}, {{{}}}, "e"};
```

For "e" it should returns 0, for "c" it should returns 2 etc. 
If there's no specified element in array, function should returns -1.

I've tried a few times, but I've no idea for elegant (and working..) solution, only this:

```
func foo(array[], var element) {
   int depth = 0;
   boolean found = false;
   boolean recursion = false;
   boolean foundInRecursion = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] instanceof array[]) {
            depth++;
            recursion = true;
            foo(array[i], element);
            recursion = false;
        } else if (array[i] == element) {
            if (recursion) {
                foundInRecursion = true;
            } else {
                found = true;
            }
        }
   }

   if (foundInRecursion) {
       return depth;
   } else if (found){
       return 0;
   } else {
       return -1;
   }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your pseudocode:

```
func depth(array[], var element) {
    /* this function returns how deep the element is in the given array */
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        current = array[i]

        if current == element {
             return 0; // element is right in the array we are given
        }

        if (current instanceof array[]) {
            // Whoa, subarray! How deep our element is in it?
            subdepth = depth(current, element)
            if subdepth >= 0 {
                // Element was found in *sub*-array, so add 1 to the depth
                return subdepth + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // If we are here, we found nothing
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The code works correctly as is. It is possible to pass the current depth in order to make the whole thing tail-recursive, I did not make it such to show the idea in a more clear way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that such elegant solution should be an iterative code that goes over each layer.

```
public int IterativeDepth(List<Object> lst, T element) 
{
    // Set the first iteration
    int depth = 0;
    List<Object> next = new List<Object>();

    while ( ! IsNullOrEmpty(lst) ) 
    // For each layer
    {
        foreach (var current in lst) 
        // For each element of a layer
        {   
            if (current instanceof T && current == element)
            // Found it, return the depth
            {
                return depth;
            }

            if (current instanceof List) {
            // It's a list, append it to the next iteration
                next.Add(current);
            }
        }

        // Set the next iteration
        lst = next;
        next.clear();
        depth += 1;
    }

    // Found nothing
    return -1;
}
```